# How to add the background shadow or gradient whatever its name in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, shadow, linear-gradients

[Check out this ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0fO9.png)

I'm trying to make tiktok clone and trying to show text on the video but when the video bg is white the text disappear as the text color is also white.I want to add kinda shadow or gradient like tiktok is in the bottom you can check the ss.

Answer (score 0):

So I would say something like this would work, that way no matter what is on the video the text will contrast it and still be visible.

```css
.video {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <div class="text">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```